# Show column value on page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-pages

How can a value (i.e. site property) be shown on the page itself?

In a page library, I've added a `Year` column. How can I display the `Year` column value for this page on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Page properties web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-page-properties-web-part-1a99cb9c-a5f1-441b-8e5d-643b0f0ff736) as shown below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank, this was it. Is there a way, to make change the appearance of the properties? It takes much space for not much information...

Comment: No, there is no such setting to change it.